# Is it possible to compare an array elements with a hard-coded initializer list without loop?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, stdarray

***[UPDATE] this question is for C and C++***

I'm trying to find an optimized way to compare an array with some literal value (magic numbers) without looping over the whole array and compare element by element. For example:

```
int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};    // or std::array<int, 3> arr{1, 2, 3} in C++;
if ({1, 2, 3} == arr)      // of course not a valid expression, but what expression can be valid instead?
{
  /* true condition */
}
```

is it even possible? or is it only possible in C++ by declaring another std::array and compare them as following:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr1{1, 2, 3};
const std::array<int, 3> arr2{1, 2, 3};
if (arr1 == arr2)
{
  /* true condition */
}
```

Comment: `std::array` is not C but C++, pick **one** language.

Comment: `std::arr1<int,3>{1, 2, 3};` is not valid syntax.

Comment: *"without looping"* Even if you don't write loop, internally there would be.

Comment: @L.F. corrected it, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Jarod42, I put it as C and C++ because I need to know if it's possible in C style coding, or I must use std::array.

Comment: In C++ you can certainly define a comparison function taking `{1, 2, 3}`. Declaring separate array would be better though, magic numbers should be avoided

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? Is it because you *assume* that it will be faster?

Comment: @Bu_ali `std::array` is not available in C.

Comment: **If** the values in question are small enough as well as their number/count, you might pack all of them into an unsigned int/long/long long, e. g.: `unsigned long const MagicNumber = 1UL << 16 | 2UL << 8 | 3UL << 0;`. You'd have to combine the other values the same way, then you could do a simple integer comparison.

Answer (score 3):

In C, I cannot think of any simpler method than `memcmp`. Here is an example:

```
int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};    
const int cmp[3] = {1, 2, 3};
if (memcmp(arr, cmp, sizeof(arr))       
{
  /* true condition */
}
```

Do note that there's no protection against reading values outside the array. `memcmp` will compare `sizeof(arr)` bytes, so you have to make sure that `cmp` have the same size.

> without looping over the whole array and compare element by element.

That's impossible. You can hide the loop so that you don't see it, but internally there will ALWAYS be a loop if you want to compare two arrays. How are you going to find out if two elements are equal if you do not compare them? Checking if two arrays are equal is O(n) no matter what you do.

There are ways to speed this up by for instance doing the comparison `a[0] == b[0]` and `a[1] == b[1]` at the same time, but that's architecture specific, and the time complexity will still be O(n).

Comment: Is it still *O(n)* when all *n* comparisons are done simultaneously? ;-)

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Yes, because no computer can do more than a finite number of comparisons at the same time.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Well, O(n/k) is still O(n), even if it's faster.

Comment: I  think he wanted just to use operators - not function calls. In C it is not possible

Comment: If we are fully strict, even arbitrary arrays are O(1), as we have a limited set of elements (at most `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` array elements – just joking around...).

Comment: `a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2] && ...` (fix array size provided) would correspond to manual loop unrolling. Would that still count as *'looping over the array'*? See similar comment to other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185134/1312382)...

Comment: @Aconcagua In practice, the maximum size of an array is always WAY higher than the maximum of simultaneous operations.

Comment: @klutt Well, re-read my comment, please: *'fix array size provided'*. As `std::array` seems to be an option, we seem to have the same size *always*, e. g. 3 as in question (thus O(1) problem then). For arbitrary arrays, we'd have to use `std::vector` instead – and then no manual loop unrolling possible any more...

Comment: @Bob__ Doesn't it depend on *k*? if *n* is always less or equal *k* Then is it still *O(n)* or - is it  *O(k)* which is *O(1)*?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk If we assume that `k` is a constant then you are right so far. `n` then has an upper bound (that upper bound could even be greater than `k` – see my fun comment above, which actually is true), and if you have an upper bound for input size, you *always* have O(1). If k is *not* a constant, then if it grew faster than n, we'd get faster on input size growing. Impossible. If n grows faster, then it will at some point get greater than k, thus precondition failing. So n and k can only grow in constant ratio, and we again get O(1).

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` is only available since C++11

This should be possible :

```
if (arr == std::array<int,3>{1,2,3})
```

Since C++17, we have deduction guides, so this should work :

```
if (arr == std::array{1,2,3})
```

Comment: That just hides the loop away. If still an acceptable answer now depends on question author just not wanting to have to write the loop explicitly (then fine) or if she/he wants to avoid any hidden loops as well (then failing)...

Comment: @Aconcagua depends on the implementation, compiler, optimization,... . Could be a SIMD processor instruction?

Comment: Not only implementation/compiler, but *system* as well (needs to support SIMD operations). *And* of the number of elements in the array. Starting at a certain amount, even a SIMD machine would have to loop. Not sure if we can assume always only 3 elements for granted. So we'd have to distinguish, in specific scenarios, we indeed might get along without loops, in general not.

Comment: With only three elements in the array I'd expect the compiler do loop unrolling, even if we have a non-SIMD machine. Would an unrolled loop still count as loop???

Comment: @Aconcagua Does it change the observable behavior? No. So it's a loop :-p